# I have a hardwired ceiling light . I didn't know it was not switched. What is the easiest way to control (on/off) it?

Tags: ceiling, light

I didn't realize a ceiling lamp was not switched (hardwired) I need a solution

Comment: @DanielGriscom, I don't see how this is a shopping question -- it's asking for a solution to switching a light, not a specific product.

Comment: run wiring to a wall switch

Answer (score 3):

Easiest?  Probably one of [these](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Project-Source-660-Watt-Black-Medium-Light-Socket-Adapter-with-Pull-Chain/3775055?):

[image: Pull Chain Adapter]
(Image curtesy of Lowes; not an endorsement)

That will add a pull chain switch to a simple light socket.  Extra chain can be clipped on if you need longer length.

Other options would be:

- Replace the fixture with one with a built-in switch
- Run some wiring to add a switch loop to a standard light switch (possibly required by code if the room doesn't have another light)
- Add a smart relay module behind the fixture in the box, and control the light with an app, remote, or smart home device
- Like Phil suggests, put a smart light bulb in the fixture and control the light with an app, remote, or smart home device

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably to replace the bulb with an LED bulb that includes WiFi control via your tablet or cell phone. Your claim of a non-switched fixture is suspicious, though. How do you know?

Comment: I agree. In my area the only built-in lighting that is not switch controlled are the old style wall fixtures that used a rotary or pull-chain switch, found on old houses. Never on the ceiling...

Comment: It's not that unlikely if the house is a certain age -- I have several non-switched ceiling fixtures in my house.  Closet lights with pull chains, ceiling fans that are controlled only from their pull chain, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these type sockets. They screw into the fixture and then the bulb screws into the new socket. The remote control then operates the new socket.

[image]

Picture from Walmart

Answer (score 0):

I think [This remote switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07S2RM95K) may be what you need. (*There are several brands that do the same thing*)

It is receiver with a remote switch, it works quite well and  will solve your problem.

You wire in the little receiver unit to the fixture inside the electrical box and you can put the wireless remote switch any place you like. The convenience of a wall switch,  as opposed to a smart bulb where you have to find your phone, open an app and negotiate to the bulb interface.

You can get more then one switch for the same receiver or visa versa.